# Control points display location changes with scale

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm trying to georeference an image by choosing points from Map (imported from Google hybrid) however the resulting tif is in no way located similar to the points (in fact the control points don't even fall inside the georeferenced image). The residual is in the thousands. I chose 3 points and used Linear transformation. I'm using WGS84 (EPSG:4326)

Also the display of the CP move as I zoom in and out of the map.

QGIS browser 2.4.0

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your question to mention the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Google hybrid as reference Map (supposed by using the QGIS Openlayers plugin) , the CRS should be set to EPSG:3857.

If you want to use lat/lon coordinates as reference, you must have a datasource that is in EPSG:4326, or read out the coordinates from an imprinted graticule and enter them manually.